# Is it possible to override properties in xml-files with ant?

Tags: java, xml, ant, properties

Let's say I have an xml file with this part:

```
<tag name="key" value="${tag.val}"/>
```

This xml file is part of a project which is built with ant. Is it possible to inject some concrete value during the build process?

I want to have something like this in the built output:

```
<tag name="key" value="realvalue"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using a `filterset`:

```
<copy args="tocopy" task="here">
    <filterset begintoken="$${" endtoken="}">
        <filter token="tag.val" value="realvalue"/>
    </filterset>
</copy>
```

You can also include a `filtersfile` as a property file which contains key/value pairs.

Of course, you also have the more simple option to source a properties file in your build file. Ant won't yell at you if it does not exist, just make sure it exists when you invoke the build file...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filterset to replace tokens in a file.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html